# How to join with an or clause in Fluent LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to join two tables.

The TSQL would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM User u INNER JOIN Hierarchy h ON u.OrganisationId = h.OrganisationId 
   OR u.OrganisationId = h.OwnerOrganisationId
```

I have searched and no one has an answer for this with fluent. The closest I can think of is this:

```
var join1 = context.User.Join(context.Hierarchy, u => u.OrganisationId, h => h.OrganisationId, uh => new {u, h});
var join2 = context.User.Join(context.Hierarchy, u => u.OrganisationId, h => h.OwnerOrganisationId, uh => new {u, h});
var desiredResult = join1.Union(join2);
```

This seems like it could be highly inefficient though.

Comment: Did you look at the optimized execution plan?

Comment: I wonder what the execution plan would look like for a cross join and filter in the where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fluent syntax**

```
var orJoin = context.User.SelectMany(
                u => context.Hierarchy.Where(h => u.OrganisationId == h.OrganisationId || u.OrganisationId == h.OwnerOrganisationId),
                (u, h) => new { u, h }
             );
```

---

**Query syntax**

```
var orJoin = from u in context.User
             from h in context.Hierarchy
             where u.OrganisationId == h.OrganisationId || u.OrganisationId == h.OwnerOrganisationId
             select new { u, h };
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply. This wasn't a direct solution but helped me work out how to solve the particular problem myself.